# Displaying Laravel foreach results

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.8

Below is my controller code.

```php
foreach ($events as $eventId) {
    $eventArray[] = Events::where('id', $eventId['event_id'])->get();
}
```

**View**

```php
@foreach ($eventArray as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The result obtained is as follows.

```
[{"id":1,"event_title":"yoga","event_date":"2019-06-24 00:00:00"}]
```

How can I display the above results in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change get to first as you are fetching event id wise data,

```
// first here to fetch one data
$eventArray[] = Events::where('id',$eventId['event_id'])->first();
```

Then in blade you can access with object syntax as `->`

```
@foreach ($eventArray as $key => $value)
{{ dd($value)}}
<!-- or -->
{{ $value->id }}
@endforeach
```

Then you will know how to use it.

Recommended approach,

```
// fetch the required event ids
$eventIds     = array_column($events, "event_id");
// then fetch the data for those ids
$eventArray = Events::whereIn('id', $eventIds)->get();
```

Comment: thank you so much... it worked :)..soon I will accept this answer :)

Comment: Welcome! Happy to Help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for that loop in your controller:

```
$events = Events::whereIn('id', array_column($events, 'event_id'))->get();

return $this->view('yourview', compact($events));
```

In your view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Title</th>
             <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($events as $event)
        <tr>
             <td>{{$event->event_title}}</td>
             <td>{{$event->event_date}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```